# glGenTextures with zero textures

Tags: opengl, zero

Simple question: What happens when I call `glGenTextures(0, someptr);`, generating zero textures? I have a function which generates textures based on a number given by a parameter, which may be 0. I did not find anything in the OpenGL reference pages, Google or StackOverflow. Is it completely undefined (not even defined as undefined behaviour) and therefore dependent on the driver?

Comment: If you want to avoid any potential problems, you could just make your function check whether the parameter is 0 before calling `glGenTextures`.

Comment: Of course, but I'm just curious about the behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be likely just to take the spec at its literal word and assume that the function will "return 0 previously unused texture names in [the array pointed to by the second parameter]". Making it a no-op, in effect.

Comment: @Kapichu FWIW, [here's a copy of the OpenGL 2.1 spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec21.20061201.pdf), which is a little dated, but for GenTextures() I would think is still accurate. See page 183 for details, if you're curious.

Comment: The latest spec has only one error listed for `glGenTextures()`: "An INVALID_VALUE error is generated if n is negative." So 0 looks completely legal, and will indeed generate 0 texture names.

Comment: correct. I just tested it and works, the content of pointer is not changed (so no names generated)